# Cannot get id of link clicked

Tags: jquery

I am getting id is undefined.
http://jsfiddle.net/valamas/YUPWu/

I am hoping someone will pick up my (trivial?) error.

thanks

Comment: i am embarrassed posting this. maybe coffee will fix me up.

Comment: `$(this)` is coming up blank because you aren't passing anything to the function.. there isn't anything for it to reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because `this` is inaccessible. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nawazhi/YUPWu/3/)

```
$(function ()
{
    $(document).on('click', "#MyId", function () { MyId_Click(this); });
});
function MyId_Click(obj)
{
    var theId = $(obj).attr('id'); 
    alert(theId);
}
​
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because $(this) is referring to nothing?  $(this) usually means your selected item.. which in your case is nothing since inside that function it's not pointing to any element.  You can do it like this

```
$(function (){
   $(document).on('click', "#MyId", function () { 
       var theId = $(this).prop('id'); //$(this).id does not work either.
       alert(theId);
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YUPWu/1/